# Select count of distinct column value, excluding duplicate values of another column

Tags: mysql, sql

sorry for the confusing title. Let me elaborate.
I have a table called `searches`. This table has a `search_term` column and a `customer_id` column. Each row represents a value (`search_term`) that a customer (`customer_id`) has searched.

```
search_term | customer_id
'test'      |           1
'test'      |           1
'test'      |           2
'test'      |           3
'test 2'    |           1
'test 2'    |           2
```

I am interested in finding out how many times a distinct `search_term` value appears. This is easy enough.

```
SELECT
    Lower(s1.`search_term`) AS 'Search Term',
    COUNT(s1.`search_term`) AS 'Number Of Requests'
FROM `search_logs` AS s1
GROUP BY Lower(s1.`search_term`)
ORDER BY `Number Of Requests`  DESC
```

The results of this query would be:

```
Search Term | Number Of Requests
'test'      |                  4
'test 2'    |                  2
```

**The tricky part (for me) is that I do not want to include duplicate searches by the same customer.
So, that means that the desired results from this test data would be**:

```
Search Term | Number Of Requests
'test'      |                  3
'test 2'    |                  2
```

(Because the customer_id = 1 searched for 'test' twice.)

I bet the answer is probably very simple, but I'm still a novice so I apologize!
My best attempt at the correct query is:

```
            SELECT
                Lower(s1.`search_term`) AS 'Search Term',
                COUNT(s1.`search_term`) AS 'Number Of Requests'
            FROM `searches` AS s1
            JOIN `searches` AS s2
                ON s1.`search_term` = s2.`search_term`
                AND s1.`customer_id`!= s2.`customer_id`
            ORDER BY `Number Of Requests` DESC
```

The results from this query are definitely not right..

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Question was answered, thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if I'm missing something : You could use `count` with `distinct`

```
 select search_term, count(distinct customer_id) as number_of_requests
 from table 
 group by search_term
```

Comment: ...I think this is right! Haha! I knew it would be something simple like that >.<. Thanks for the help man!